# How do I customize player implemented using SWFobject?

Tags: swfobject

I am using SWFobject to implement player from slideshare.

Using embedSWF method to get player:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://static.slidesharecdn.com/swf/doc_player.swf", "player", "700", "392", "8", null, flashvars, params, atts);
```

its giving me player correctly but now I want to customize options from player i.e I don't want options like zoom in, zoom out,show on slideshare etc currently which are there on player.

can I able to customize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWF Object can be embeded in your code using following

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, id, width, height, version, installSwfurl,
                    flashvars, params, attributes, callbackFn)
```

As you can see it has params as one of its parameter. Params can have menu, id, play, loop, quality, scale, etc.

To remove control menu keep menu as false. In your case, try below code

```
var params = {
  menu: "false"
};
swfobject.embedSWF("http://static.slidesharecdn.com/swf/doc_player.swf", "player", "700", "392", "8", null, flashvars, params, atts);
```

I am not 100% sure about this as I have not tried it.

For more reference you can look at

[flash-object-embed-tag-attributes](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)

[swfobject/wiki/documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)

Comment: Sir, I am tried  same thing  but is seems to be not working for me. there is not any effect of "menu" parameter. i.e even if I set it is 'true' or 'false' I am getting same player.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a SWFObject issue -- you're attempting to customize the look and feel of the SlideShare Player, which means you need to use their API. This is independent of SWFObject.

Please refer to the [SlideShare Player API documentation](http://www.slideshare.net/developers/playerapi).

Comment: Thank you. I have gone through slideshare player API documentation but I didn't get any option to customize player.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What you desire may not be possible. Regardless, it's not a SWFObject issue. SWFObject simply places the SWF into your HTML -- no more, no less.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted with slideshare about that.